# R data table merge vs Stata merge

Tags: r, merge, data.table, stata

I am comparing R data.table merge with Stata's merge command.

Say we have two datasets, X and Y. Both have a common key `id`.

Stata has 1:1 `merge` which means datasets will be `merge`d one to one on a unique id. If we are using dataset X in Stata and wish to merge with Y, "master" is X and "using" is Y.

```
merge 1:1 id using Y, options
```

Stata further gives you a choice of as they called it "matched result". Basically it is a choice of 3 values.

```
Numeric Code    Description
           1    observation appeared in X only
           2    observation appeared in Y only
           3    observation appeared in both only
```

I believe that in R data.table, a 1:1 merge it is:

For "merged result" numeric code 1, you do LEFT JOIN. Then any result not appearing in X will be given NA. So we need to do

```
Y[X, on=.(id)] or merge(X,Y, all.x=TRUE, on="id")
```

For "merged result" numeric code 2, you do RIGHT JOIN. Then any result not appearing in Y will be given NA. So we need to do

```
X[Y, on=.(id)] or merge(X,Y, all.y=TRUE, on="id")
```

For "merged result" numeric code 3, you do INNER JOIN. It only displays data that exist in both X and Y.

```
X[Y, nomatch=0, on=.(id)] or merge(X,Y, all=FALSE, on="id")
```

Is this correct? I am comfortable with Stata choice 3 which is basically INNER JOIN. But I am confused with choices 1 and 2. If you further do na.omit(), it will revert to choice 3. Is that correct?

And what can I do in R for 1:m or m:1 one to many and vice versa?

FYI for Stata manual:

```
https://www.stata.com/manuals/dmerge.pdf
```

For data.table merge:

```
https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/52230_5ae0d25125b544caab32f75f0360e775.html
```

Comment: I guess `merge(X, Y, all.x = ..., all.y = ...)` covers it, as your link says. The faq `library(data.table); vignette("datatable-faq")` also points to the `nomatch=` argument in `X[Y]`. You should not do `na.omit` to handle any merging, since there may be legitimate NA values that belong in the merged result.

Comment: Small corrections FYI. "Stata" is so spelled, not STATA. `merge` is a Stata command, not a function. More importantly for this question, the word "choice" is not a good description here: rather, the results 1, 2, 3 are possible results of a `merge` depending on where observations are found, in both or either of two datasets. The user can, if you like, choose what to do with such results after `merge`, but the choice is not part of the `merge` instruction.

Comment: Why cite the Stata 13 manuals? As I write https://www.stata.com/manuals/dmerge.pdf contains the manuals for Stata 15, although I don't think any detail important for this question has changed in recent versions.

Comment: The manual is what I come up when i search in google. Let me cite it with the latest dmerge. Basically at uni I have Stata but I am away and dont have Stata at home so i need to translate all the codes to R... Any ideas on both suggest and I believe data.table merge is similar to SQL merge.

Comment: I am quite familiar with Stata, but no kind of R expert, and have never merged in R, so the question is wide open to anyone who knows about that side.

Comment: Maybe you could narrow down your question and give a concrete example of interest? A tutorial comparing the two merging tools (merge/joinby/cross vs merge/X[Y] with their various arguments) would be too broad for this site. The 1:1, 1:m, m:1 rules are not enforced in R except in special cases, like `X = data.table(a = c(1L, 1L, 2L)); Y = data.table(a = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)); X[Y, on=.(a)]` where it stops based on the rule of thumb that you probably don't want more rows than nrow(X) + nrow(Y).

Comment: I believe one to many or many to one merge in Stata is that there exist a very unique identifier like row numbers which uniquely identifies to which role and other than that it has the same operation as one to one operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not very familiar with Stata, but I think I can explain the merge (from base, which data.table adapted)

Let's say you have these two data frames:

```
A <- data.frame(id = c(1,2,4,5),
                obs1 = c(100, 120, 500, 70))

B <- data.frame(id = c(1,3,4,5),
                obs2 = c("a", "c", "t", "r"))
```

You can join them in these ways:

**Inner join**

```
merge(A, B)
```

You'll have only the intersects of A and B, e.g. ids 1, 4 and 5.

**Left join**

```
merge(A, B, all.x = TRUE)
```

You'll have the intersect info, plus whatever is present in A but not B. e.g. 1, 2, 4 and 5

**Right join**

```
merge(A, B, all.y = TRUE)
```

Here, you'll have the intersect info, plus whatever is in B but not A. e.g. ids 1, 3, 4 and 5

**Full join**

```
merge(A, B, all.x = TRUE, all.y = TRUE)
```

Here, you'll have the union of ids present in A and B. e.g. all ids, 1-5.

---

Alternatively, take a look at dplyr's join functions. They have `inner_join`, `left_join`, `right_join`, etc.

Comment: This confirms my answer and is the same as what I thinks. I believe one to many or many to one merge in Stata is that there exist a very unique identifier like row numbers which uniquely identifies to which role and have the same operation as one to one operation.